# Linear actuator. Monitor end switch with arduino

Tags: arduino, sensor, actuator

For a hobby project I am developing a solar tracker. For this I obtained a linear actuator. It contains a DC motor, 2 Hall sensors and an end switch. I am using an Arduino Uno and a Polulu motor driver for control. Below is a link to a simple electrical schematic of the actuator

http://www.solar-motors.com/inc/getfile.php?id=783163FD-16DB-4AE0-9A48-C1CD71093105

I have managed to run the motor and read out the hall sensors. My problem is with the end switch. I am not sure how to wire this and read this signal.

I am powering the Hall Vcc with 5V form the arduino, which works well with the hall sensors, but when I connect the end switch to a digital input pin I get no signal when the actuator is at its end.

Does somebody have an idea on how to set this up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a pull-up resistor from the output to VCC.

10k ohm will probably work just fine.

Perhaps you can use the internal pullups in the Arduino inputs.

Comment: The question refers to the end switch and not open collector outputs.

Comment: @Andyaka You are right. :-)  I edited the answer. A pull-up should still do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for that. To add to that, I have a 24V power supply (Meanwell SDR-240-24) which I use to power the DC motor. Can I than also use this same power supply to power the hall sensor and end switch? This in combination with the pull-up resistors.

Comment: @roadrunner38 If you connect the 24VDC supply to the hall sensor, you are operating at absolute max rating. I would use a lower voltage. For the pull-up on the end switch, you should use VCC from the Arduino. If you connect it to 24VDC the Arduino will die.

Comment: OK. I managed to get it working. Many thanks!